# class diagram java application

Tags: uml

Programming language: java . Problems with class diagram.

Given a class named Bridge is the following representation correct?

My concerns is about how to deal with declarations such as:
private Semaphore semaphore;

This is the attributes/method declaration:

```
public class Bridge {
    private Semaphore semaphore;
    private Lock lock:
    private Condition waitingCond;
    private int nNorthCars; .......
    public void getIn(int direction) throws InterruptedException{
    .....
The same goes for getOut()....
}
```

UML representation:

```
 ---------------------
    Bridge
    ---------------------
    - semaphore: Semaphore
    - lock: Lock
    - waitingCond: Condition
    - nNorthCars: int
    - nSouthCars: int
    ---------------------
    + getIn(): void
    + getOut(): void
    ---------------------
```

Furthermore, given the fact that variables inside the main function are supposed to be local, am I right in thinking that they should be treated as private? 
For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
...........
int nThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
long time = 0; 
...}
```

Here's the UML implementation:

```
---------------------
Main
---------------------
- nThreads: int
- time: long
---------------------
+ main()
---------------------
```

Symbols: - (private), + (public)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UML in general is meant to be implementation / language agnostic - when reading a UML diagram you shouldn't know or care what language it is implemented in. Also, a class diagram is meant to represent (or model) the types / classes / concepts of a domain problem and their relationships. Hence, you shouldn't worry about local variables within a method since this is both an implementation detail and doesn't relate to the relationship with other classes or concepts.

It appears that you are trying to use UML to model (or reverse engineer) a Java program and that you want to include every variable in the program as part of your class diagram. This is not the approach you should be taking.

`SemaPhore`, `lock` and `waitingCondition` are all implementation details and do not convey any useful information about `Bridge`'s behaviour or `Bridge`'s relationship with other classes. `nNorthCars` and `nSouthCars` are private - does it make sense in your model to expose these as public properties? Do other classes / concepts in your model need to know about these? If no to these questions, then you can probably drop these from the class diagram too. You may want to keep them if you are going to model some method of Bridge perhaps in an activity diagram. Bridge probably wants to look like this in UML:

```
    ---------------------
    Bridge
    ---------------------

    ---------------------
    + getIn(): void
    + getOut(): void
    ---------------------
```

If Bridge has a relationship with something else (perhaps a collection of cars) then you can model that, since this that relationship is externally visible to other concepts in your model.

`Main` looks like your program entry point, again, it may not be necessary to model this as such. If `Main` aggregates all the other (or most other) classes / concepts then go ahead and model that as such, otherwise it becomes an implementation detail.

Finally, UML is really meant to model your concepts that you then implement in code. It appears that you are doing the reverse of this. Reverse engineering and round-tripping are OK to a certain extent, but be careful otherwise you end up hacking in UML and generating code from it. The idea of UML is to model your domain and validate this model before you cut code.

Hope this helps...